# how to use materializejs components with meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, meteor, materialize

I use [materialize framework](http://materializecss.com) for my front-end meteor app.

I have installed materialize package and jQuery package, and I can use componants that use only css but when it came to js componants I can't find where to put the **Initialization**.

For example I want to add [dropdown](http://materializecss.com/dropdown.html) I take the HTML code and I put it inside my HTML file 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsrQj.png)

After that I didn't know how and where can i put the js or jquery code 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4Dfq.png)

So I want to know where and how I use the js or the jquery lines please.

Comment: Please put your code [_in the question itself_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). You've also only provided us with code from the library examples - you need to add the code from your own project and show us what you've tried.

Comment: I don't have the code in my project. That's what I want to know how to put the code from the library example inside a meteor project

Comment: You must have _something_ that you've tried already? The onus is on you to attempt this yourself first, and update your question with your code.